# Spark Out of Memory exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I receive 10 GB file everyday containing employee details.Need to select the latest records from previous day and current day file.Ex: 6th August and 7th August files need to compared on time-Stamp column and select latest records

- 6th August File

  ```
  emp-id   name   dept        phone-No    time-Stamp
  1       Jhon   Sales       817234518   12-6-2019     
  2       Marry  Production  927234565   4-3-2019 
  3       James  Marketing   625234522   21-1-2019
  ```
- 7th August File

  ```
  emp-id   name   dept        phone-No    time-Stamp
  1       Jhon   Sales       817234518   12-7-2019     
  4       Jerry  Sales       653214442   12-7-2019 
  3       James  Marketing   625234522   2-6-2019
  ```
- Expected output

  ```
  emp-id   name   dept        phone-No    time-Stamp
  1       Jhon   Sales       817234518   12-7-2019     
  2       Marry  Production  927234565   4-3-2019 
  3       James  Marketing   625234522   2-5-2019
  4       Jerry  Sales       653214442   12-7-2019
  ```

I tried solutions as below and got expected result.

```
 val mergedDF = currentDayDF.union(previousDayDF)

mergedDF.show(false)

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("emp-id").orderBy(col("timeStamp").desc)
val latestForEachKey = mergedDF.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec))
                               .filter(col("rank") === 1)
                               .drop("rank")
```

Questions

1. Every day's input file size is 10 GB, What if cluster memory(total executors memory) is less than 20 GB to load both data sets (previous day and current day) will spark throw Out of Memory exception?

   I thought, spark divides large file as partitions to process, hence at the beginning only few partitions are loaded into executors memory, transformations applied and saved intermediate resultant dataset to secondary memory and then process is continued for remaining partitions.But parition by requires all the partitions of data as its wider transformation my guess is wrong. So will spark throw OOM exception?

Comment: Please try to limit each question post to a single question, see e.g.: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post. You write that you tried the `join` above. What was the result and how does it differ from what you wanted?

Comment: I edited  question and included output. Thanks

Comment: I downvoted this question and I'm voting to close it because it's too broad. Like @Shaido stated : "limit each question post to a single question". Also some of your questions have already been answer on the site. You just need to look for them.

Comment: I have changed the question scope as per the comments received please help me with answer. I have searched for the answer before posting the question

Comment: @Niketa: To me it still looks like two separate questions? One about the memory problem and one about how to do the join to get the expected output. Or does the memory exception occur when running that code?

Comment: @Shaido ,I already found the solution for expected result. My question is only regarding memory management. How spark handles data which cannot fit into executor memory

Comment: @Niketa: I see, that's great :). In that case, the input samples and code in the question are uninteresting, correct? The actual question is everything after the `1.`?

Comment: I just provided sample inputs to elaborate question, Actual input file size is 10 GB. Two such files need to be compared, using partition by and rank. My question was how spark handles huge data which cannot be fit into cluster memory.

Answer (score -1):

Partitions are used for parallel execution. Spark will try to load all the 20GB data simultaneously in all the available partitions. If the combined memory of all executors where partitions are created is less than 20 GB then it will throw out of memory error